# Where are Thunar's favorites/shortcuts stored?

Tags: thunar

I would like to add the folders that I drag & drop in the sidebar to my dot files repository.

However, when I go into the `~/.config/Thunar` and I looked at all the files, I don't see my folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunar uses GTK3.0 shortcuts stored in `$USER/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks!  This was super important for me because Thunar 1.8.4 is somehow incapable of correctly saving the full path when creating a WebDAV shortcut. Instead of saving `davs://domain.com/remote.php/dav/files/user` it would only save `davs://domain.com/remote.php/dav`, which would then fail when clicked on. Also, note that Thunar immediately reflects changes to this file - no restart required!